# Creating a spectrogram in iphone for a fixed length of data samples

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am pretty new to iOS programming and i need to create and display a spectrogram given a fixed length array of samples. Is it possible to display it using core plot? If so, how? I would really love to have some help on this.

Comment: Which part specifically do you need help with ?

Comment: Show us that you have tried it yourself before you asked here.

Comment: I basically need help on the interface, particularly on how to display a spectrogram once its calculated. The algorithm for computing is a spectrogram is pretty simple. But I dont know how to use core plot to display, though I have heard it is possible to display areas filled with colors in the graph. I have seen examples of core plot which demonstrate its use in showing curves. But I want to plot fills of colors based on the computed spectrogram.

Comment: In keeping with the ["what have you tried?" theme](http://whathaveyoutried.com), I'd recommend you read up on Core Plot (since you mention it's what you've heard of), try to implement something, and refine your question when you run into trouble with a specific portion.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a 2D color bitmap and displaying that bitmap using core graphics instead of using core plot.